# Select an element from the result of another select using a single query string

Tags: java, jsoup

Suppose I have a jsoup query:

```
"main#main-content > ol > li:eq(0) a"
```

It returns all the `a` elements contained in the first line of a table (works as expected).

Now I would like to extract the last of those elements. How can I do it by using a single jsoup query? (aka. How to rewrite the jsoup query above to say that I don't want ALL the `a` elements but only the last one?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:last-child`, like so:

```
main#main-content > ol > li:eq(0) a:last-child
```

Live example: [https://try.jsoup.org/~Lim_aO1f6rn6oGokJaogXHvgJ0M](https://try.jsoup.org/%7ELim_aO1f6rn6oGokJaogXHvgJ0M)

Reference: [Selector API](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

---

**EDIT**

Since the OP failed to provide specific HTML inputs and desired results, it wasn't immediately clear what *exactly* the OP wanted to achieve. With more information provided, this *currently* seems to be the answer:

```java
// Document doc = ...;
Element result = doc.select("main#main-content > ol > li:eq(0) a:last-child").last();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Janez, but it doesn't work in any situation.  
For example https://try.jsoup.org/~32BGJEfgsvMU10z7FRHqMplH4P0

Comment: @user2572526 Does the edit answer your question?

Comment: thanks, but actually also the new answer doesn't solve my problem. 
I would need to have only a JSoup query. 
In your answer there is a new call to amethod - last()

Comment: @user2572526 You can *always* write a CSS Selector query that returns what you want for a *specific* HTML input. But I don't think you can write a general query for your use-case, however, you can achieve what you want with the help of the jsoup API. AFAIK, you can't run subqueries using CSS Selectors.